# ColdFusion and Installed Fonts

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, cfpdfform

Is there a quick way to test each system installed font in code to see if ColdFusion can read it or not? I'm having an issue because CFPDFFORM errors because there are fonts installed in my computer that ColdFusion cannot read.

Comment: Fonts that coldfusion can not read ? Did you get an error message specifying that or did you conclude it ? Please post an example of non working code together with an explanation of what is not working and an eventual error message

Comment: @Bartdude - See his [previous question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289795/cfpdfform-populate-error-java-lang-nullpointerexception-platform-locale-and)  I believe this question is related to that error.

Comment: That is correct Miquel-F. This question is related to my previous question.